# Is it possible for graphite which has shed off metal rods during water electrolysis to bond with the hydrogen being produced to form hydrocarbons?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, electrolysis, hydrocarbons

I recently conducted a simple experiment for school involving the electrolysis of water.

I changed the concentrations of an ionic compound to determine its effect on the rate at which the products of the lysis of water are formed. I used graphite rods for the electrodes. These shed quite heavily.

I noted this down in my qualitative data, but I was wondering whether this excess graphite may have bonded with some of the hydrogen produced at the cathode to form hydrocarbons?

Comment: Probably not. It's rather weird that was any damage to electrodes, though. I think yo should provide more details.

Comment: So the graphite is coming from graphite rods. I have used graphite rods for electrolysis and found they shed. I assumed it was a mechanical affect of oxygen bubbles forming below the surface. I switched to platinum .